# My insert query only executes once

Tags: php, insert

I have a registration page that works perfectly fine when it the first user registers. When the second user registers the INSERT query outputs an error. Here is my code:

```
if ($err_found != true)
    $saveData = "INSERT INTO anc_user_info (CardNumber, UserName, Password, Name, 
                         Surname, IDNumber, Province, Region, Branch, Gender, Language, 
                         PhysicalAddress, Profession, Category, TelNoW, TelNoH, Email, 
                         Cell, ProfilePic, TransactionRef, DepositAmount, DepositerName, 
                         Declaration, UserID, Status, CreateDate) 
            VALUES( '$CardNumber', '$UserName', md5('$Password'), '$Name', '$Surname', 
                        '$IDNumber', '$Province', '$Region', '$Branch', '$Gender', 
                        '$Language', '$PhysicalAddress', '$Profession', '$Category', 
                        '$TelNoW', '$TelNoH', '$Email', '$Cell', '$ProfilePic', 
                        '$TransactionRef', '$DepositAmount', '$DepositerName', 
                        '$Declaration', '$UserID', 0, NOW())" ;
```

Comment: A common cause for only being able to insert once is that subsequent inserts violate a unique constraint. You should enable error reporting on your database connection and check the actual error the database returns to verify this.

Comment: By the way, you should consider binding your values to a prepared statement instead of concatenating them into your SQL. The way you are doing it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: What is the error it outputs..?

Comment: I managed to fix this thanks. My SQL table was set to VARCHAR instead of INT for one of the coloumns. I am interested though. How would one know to inject when because some of the info is taken from GET and SESSION variables, not all values to be entered into the database appear in the form input fields and the table columns are set to null and others not.